# Auto-Update Enterprise (intern) Apps

Tags: android, updates, auto-update, enterprise, android-update-app

So, is there a realiable way to update enterprise/intern apps remotelly?
I work in a company that spreads across my state, including some areas that the access is dificult, so I can't send someone to locally update the app everytime there's a new release.

I'm working with Android/Java at the moment, and we also use Azure DevOps to store the repositories.
I tryied App Center from Microsoft but didn't understood if that could help me update my app or not.
Also, we don't want to publish the application to the PlayStore and make it public. Unless, of course, if that's the only way.

Thank you for your time reading this, I will keep searching something related to this and also share here any solution that I can find.

Answer (score 1):

There's different ways to do so I'll say some but there's definitely more.

You can use [`Push-link`](https://www.push-link.com/), read about it it does more or less what you are looking for.

Perhaps could work uploading the `.apk` to `Google Play` and just publish it for beta testers, here's an old [`Google Play Private App Guide`](https://blog.google/documents/12/Google_Play_private_app_guide_-_FINAL_Nov17_1_1.pdf/) pdf and perhaps it doesn't work anymore but give it a try.

Also what you tried with `App Center` perhaps what you are looking for is [`Distribution In-App Updates`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/appcenter/distribution/inappupdates)

*Note: This is not recommended to avoid by passing Google Play to distribute an app*

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just for my information, it's not recommended to avoid google play bypass even if my app is for collaborators only?

Comment: It's not recommended because if it does not pass by google play security you might not warn about vulnerabilities of that app